# Angular Create Pure HTML Form Inspired By Google Form

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, typescript

My goal is find the way how to generate pure HTML file from created form in Angular which was inspired by Google Form.

Example of generated JSON:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "descriptionTest",
  "pages": [
    {
      "id": "b8107c034ded6bf430488ca30d524bed",
      "number": 1,
      "name": null,
      "description": null,
      "pageFlow": {
        "nextPage": true,
        "label": "mwForm.pageFlow.goToNextPage"
      },
      "elements": [
        {
          "id": "7180d9e3d0c341bb99c91c73d5b97351",
          "orderNo": 1,
          "type": "question",
          "question": {
            "id": "ed9a53e5ebc4fd4cdf84686743c0b939",
            "text": "short text",
            "type": "text",
            "required": true,
            "pageFlowModifier": false
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "3f215923f068d5355ce9dcc61aa340c7",
          "orderNo": 2,
          "type": "question",
          "question": {
            "id": "46d605c6b29161e49918733ea2c21b10",
            "text": "long text",
            "type": "textarea",
            "required": true,
            "pageFlowModifier": false
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "2da74f344ce74b0c9c501f05dd27b94a",
          "orderNo": 3,
          "type": "question",
          "question": {
            "id": "16a37f04b1f2c4ed9ccad0f90c202f3e",
            "text": "radio question",
            "type": "radio",
            "required": true,
            "offeredAnswers": [
              {
                "id": "c1860469d05cb0be1ef6c254809c207e",
                "orderNo": 2,
                "value": "bbbb",
                "pageFlow": {
                  "nextPage": true,
                  "label": "mwForm.pageFlow.goToNextPage"
                }
              }
            ],
            "otherAnswer": true
          }
        }
      ],
      "namedPage": false,
      "isFirst": true,
      "isLast": false
    },
    {
      "id": "d7b158cc2aff4c00b3d452006d79368d",
      "number": 2,
      "name": null,
      "description": null,
      "pageFlow": {
        "nextPage": true,
        "label": "mwForm.pageFlow.goToNextPage"
      },
      "elements": [
        {
          "id": "1b183679857291f8ad46c03c3173e64d",
          "orderNo": 1,
          "type": "question",
          "question": {
            "id": "10b08afca4dff80e975f4910ee85ef3f",
            "text": "grid question",
            "type": "grid",
            "required": true,
            "grid": {
              "cellInputType": "radio",
              "rows": [
                {
                  "id": "48b09d72e6fb0d2a63985eef4018346e",
                  "orderNo": 1,
                  "label": "row 1"
                },
                {
                  "id": "f35a6e5d1ce9407b5ece224198032cb6",
                  "orderNo": 2,
                  "label": "row 2"
                }
              ],
              "cols": [
                {
                  "id": "ace63d4001112c28e97b00ff67ceeeca",
                  "orderNo": 1,
                  "label": "col 1"
                },
                {
                  "id": "24062ae1fc97dead41d337ede7f2e55e",
                  "orderNo": 2,
                  "label": "col2"
                }
              ]
            },
            "pageFlowModifier": false
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "82332304478a82ee69f2d60157930e0a",
          "orderNo": 2,
          "type": "question",
          "question": {
            "id": "dc640ed493ba5a00d4a44f3a216cfa34",
            "text": "priority list",
            "type": "priority",
            "required": true,
            "priorityList": [
              {
                "id": "c389bfb386b59483c7592719d9968d35",
                "orderNo": 1,
                "value": "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
              },
              {
                "id": "66a28c757482c280b30db318b5922201",
                "orderNo": 2,
                "value": "bbbbbbbbbb"
              },
              {
                "id": "14629777a4bda0e1d40044429aaf63f9",
                "orderNo": 3,
                "value": "cccccccccccccc"
              }
            ],
            "pageFlowModifier": false
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "358c65a9f3590235b3b9d019722f2372",
          "orderNo": 3,
          "type": "question",
          "question": {
            "id": "8666ad943291900f0e5b34bc14bb18dc",
            "text": "division",
            "type": "division",
            "required": true,
            "divisionList": [
              {
                "id": "dc3c109e947b736c49415faf0b595091",
                "orderNo": 1,
                "value": "aaaaaa"
              },
              {
                "id": "476d950019a69252524ac00d2a39ef54",
                "orderNo": 2,
                "value": "bbbbb"
              },
              {
                "id": "d9b54b9da75bdfe78d4cbc41d0cdf9e0",
                "orderNo": 3,
                "value": "cccccccc"
              }
            ],
            "pageFlowModifier": false,
            "quantity": 100,
            "unit": "%"
          }
        }
      ],
      "namedPage": false
    },
    {
      "id": "ae67e396d65e964ba1e36612447e57cb",
      "number": 3,
      "name": null,
      "description": null,
      "pageFlow": {
        "nextPage": true,
        "label": "mwForm.pageFlow.goToNextPage"
      },
      "elements": [
        {
          "id": "af32b41604fb897ffa4032d991895516",
          "orderNo": 1,
          "type": "image",
          "image": {
            "id": "4928a58daca10e16478d87681c901145",
            "align": "left"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "cd709d5bb49853e958e2492d3c2adb47",
          "orderNo": 2,
          "type": "paragraph",
          "paragraph": {
            "id": "6baa4a390481f11692bee36e7c6e1138",
            "html": "dasdas"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "36a4a1557d4ebc4a35d143bac29c807e",
          "orderNo": 3,
          "type": "question",
          "question": {
            "id": "a6ef70bda61155e438ca4e685ed6fe4a",
            "text": "sadas",
            "type": "division",
            "required": true,
            "pageFlowModifier": false,
            "divisionList": [
              {
                "id": "412fd4904cf27fe2f553aaf91743e949",
                "orderNo": 1,
                "value": null
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "namedPage": false
    },
    {
      "id": "1acecfcc6d82b1329c11e7a91c658ecc",
      "number": 4,
      "name": null,
      "description": null,
      "pageFlow": {
        "nextPage": true,
        "label": "mwForm.pageFlow.goToNextPage"
      },
      "elements": [],
      "namedPage": false
    },
    {
      "id": "5d9fc08eaac5739f574db0e5b86a6a36",
      "number": 5,
      "name": "Page name",
      "description": null,
      "pageFlow": {
        "nextPage": true,
        "label": "mwForm.pageFlow.goToNextPage"
      },
      "elements": [
        {
          "id": "99f0e2587c29cde3abb2ab2076fc375c",
          "orderNo": 1,
          "type": "paragraph",
          "paragraph": {
            "id": "12448073a8702376af0b427b63022926",
            "html": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis nunc quis nisi lacinia commodo quis in urna. Maecenas dictum urna eget fringilla vehicula. Morbi congue id dolor vel volutpat. Aenean suscipit lectus velit, eget eleifend massa pretium quis. Cras quis pharetra nulla. Proin porttitor fermentum est, eu aliquam velit porttitor quis. Sed non bibendum odio, a pellentesque neque. Donec eu lectus vitae nisl ornare aliquet. Donec ornare felis non elit malesuada tincidunt. Praesent ipsum augue, venenatis in auctor vel, aliquet et augue. Ut efficitur elit eu elit fringilla, imperdiet suscipit libero consequat. Ut in metus libero. Nullam vestibulum, augue nec varius elementum, erat orci iaculis neque, quis varius ante leo eu lectus. Vestibulum eget ante enim. Nulla lobortis, felis sed mattis posuere, urna leo pharetra mi, ut elementum augue erat sed odio. In mattis, orci nec maximus fermentum, tellus lacus porta purus, sed scelerisque massa justo id nunc."
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "2d9145a0b749ca85959268737c90029c",
          "orderNo": 2,
          "type": "image",
          "image": {
            "id": "e94d4dcdbc45d90d0561116518e13b77",
            "align": "center",
            "src": "lena.gif",
            "caption": "Image caption"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "1dfa4dc8242f7b98b5449d380fee1785",
          "orderNo": 3,
          "type": "question",
          "question": {
            "id": "7d8826e84a398532fbe78be646214eab",
            "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit?",
            "type": "textarea",
            "required": true,
            "pageFlowModifier": false
          }
        }
      ],
      "namedPage": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I expect to copy generated JSON and paste it to pure HTML template.
Please see screenshot attached bellow:
[image: JSON Model Generated Area]

Unfortunately, can't find any documentation how Pure HTML should look with Google Form generated JSON in one place.

I just tried to add this JSON here [surveyjs.io](https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library/?id=questiontype-radiogroup&platform=jQuery&theme=modern#content-js), but it turned out that he had nothing to do. - Got Error

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>One choice - Radio Group question, jQuery Survey Library Example</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/survey-jquery@1.8.75/survey.jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/survey-core@1.8.75/modern.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css"></head>
    <body>
        <div id="surveyElement" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;"></div>
        <div id="surveyResult"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
   Survey
        .StylesManager
        .applyTheme("modern");
    
    var json = {
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "descriptionTest",
  "pages": [
    {
      "id": "b8107c034ded6bf430488ca30d524bed",
      "number": 1,
      "name": null,
      "description": null,
      "pageFlow": {
        "nextPage": true,
        "label": "mwForm.pageFlow.goToNextPage"
      },
      "elements": [
        {
          "id": "7180d9e3d0c341bb99c91c73d5b97351",
          "orderNo": 1,
          "type": "question",
          "question": {
            "id": "ed9a53e5ebc4fd4cdf84686743c0b939",
            "text": "short text",
            "type": "text",
            "required": true,
            "pageFlowModifier": false
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "3f215923f068d5355ce9dcc61aa340c7",
          "orderNo": 2,
          "type": "question",
          "question": {
            "id": "46d605c6b29161e49918733ea2c21b10",
            "text": "long text",
            "type": "textarea",
            "required": true,
            "pageFlowModifier": false
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "2da74f344ce74b0c9c501f05dd27b94a",
          "orderNo": 3,
          "type": "question",
          "question": {
            "id": "16a37f04b1f2c4ed9ccad0f90c202f3e",
            "text": "radio question",
            "type": "radio",
            "required": true,
            "offeredAnswers": [
              {
                "id": "c1860469d05cb0be1ef6c254809c207e",
                "orderNo": 2,
                "value": "bbbb",
                "pageFlow": {
                  "nextPage": true,
                  "label": "mwForm.pageFlow.goToNextPage"
                }
              }
            ],
            "otherAnswer": true
          }
        }
      ],
      "namedPage": false,
      "isFirst": true,
      "isLast": false
    },
    {
      "id": "d7b158cc2aff4c00b3d452006d79368d",
      "number": 2,
      "name": null,
      "description": null,
      "pageFlow": {
        "nextPage": true,
        "label": "mwForm.pageFlow.goToNextPage"
      },
      "elements": [
        {
          "id": "1b183679857291f8ad46c03c3173e64d",
          "orderNo": 1,
          "type": "question",
          "question": {
            "id": "10b08afca4dff80e975f4910ee85ef3f",
            "text": "grid question",
            "type": "grid",
            "required": true,
            "grid": {
              "cellInputType": "radio",
              "rows": [
                {
                  "id": "48b09d72e6fb0d2a63985eef4018346e",
                  "orderNo": 1,
                  "label": "row 1"
                },
                {
                  "id": "f35a6e5d1ce9407b5ece224198032cb6",
                  "orderNo": 2,
                  "label": "row 2"
                }
              ],
              "cols": [
                {
                  "id": "ace63d4001112c28e97b00ff67ceeeca",
                  "orderNo": 1,
                  "label": "col 1"
                },
                {
                  "id": "24062ae1fc97dead41d337ede7f2e55e",
                  "orderNo": 2,
                  "label": "col2"
                }
              ]
            },
            "pageFlowModifier": false
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "82332304478a82ee69f2d60157930e0a",
          "orderNo": 2,
          "type": "question",
          "question": {
            "id": "dc640ed493ba5a00d4a44f3a216cfa34",
            "text": "priority list",
            "type": "priority",
            "required": true,
            "priorityList": [
              {
                "id": "c389bfb386b59483c7592719d9968d35",
                "orderNo": 1,
                "value": "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
              },
              {
                "id": "66a28c757482c280b30db318b5922201",
                "orderNo": 2,
                "value": "bbbbbbbbbb"
              },
              {
                "id": "14629777a4bda0e1d40044429aaf63f9",
                "orderNo": 3,
                "value": "cccccccccccccc"
              }
            ],
            "pageFlowModifier": false
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "358c65a9f3590235b3b9d019722f2372",
          "orderNo": 3,
          "type": "question",
          "question": {
            "id": "8666ad943291900f0e5b34bc14bb18dc",
            "text": "division",
            "type": "division",
            "required": true,
            "divisionList": [
              {
                "id": "dc3c109e947b736c49415faf0b595091",
                "orderNo": 1,
                "value": "aaaaaa"
              },
              {
                "id": "476d950019a69252524ac00d2a39ef54",
                "orderNo": 2,
                "value": "bbbbb"
              },
              {
                "id": "d9b54b9da75bdfe78d4cbc41d0cdf9e0",
                "orderNo": 3,
                "value": "cccccccc"
              }
            ],
            "pageFlowModifier": false,
            "quantity": 100,
            "unit": "%"
          }
        }
      ],
      "namedPage": false
    },
    {
      "id": "ae67e396d65e964ba1e36612447e57cb",
      "number": 3,
      "name": null,
      "description": null,
      "pageFlow": {
        "nextPage": true,
        "label": "mwForm.pageFlow.goToNextPage"
      },
      "elements": [
        {
          "id": "af32b41604fb897ffa4032d991895516",
          "orderNo": 1,
          "type": "image",
          "image": {
            "id": "4928a58daca10e16478d87681c901145",
            "align": "left"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "cd709d5bb49853e958e2492d3c2adb47",
          "orderNo": 2,
          "type": "paragraph",
          "paragraph": {
            "id": "6baa4a390481f11692bee36e7c6e1138",
            "html": "dasdas"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "36a4a1557d4ebc4a35d143bac29c807e",
          "orderNo": 3,
          "type": "question",
          "question": {
            "id": "a6ef70bda61155e438ca4e685ed6fe4a",
            "text": "sadas",
            "type": "division",
            "required": true,
            "pageFlowModifier": false,
            "divisionList": [
              {
                "id": "412fd4904cf27fe2f553aaf91743e949",
                "orderNo": 1,
                "value": null
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "namedPage": false
    },
    {
      "id": "1acecfcc6d82b1329c11e7a91c658ecc",
      "number": 4,
      "name": null,
      "description": null,
      "pageFlow": {
        "nextPage": true,
        "label": "mwForm.pageFlow.goToNextPage"
      },
      "elements": [],
      "namedPage": false
    },
    {
      "id": "5d9fc08eaac5739f574db0e5b86a6a36",
      "number": 5,
      "name": "Page name",
      "description": null,
      "pageFlow": {
        "nextPage": true,
        "label": "mwForm.pageFlow.goToNextPage"
      },
      "elements": [
        {
          "id": "99f0e2587c29cde3abb2ab2076fc375c",
          "orderNo": 1,
          "type": "paragraph",
          "paragraph": {
            "id": "12448073a8702376af0b427b63022926",
            "html": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis nunc quis nisi lacinia commodo quis in urna. Maecenas dictum urna eget fringilla vehicula. Morbi congue id dolor vel volutpat. Aenean suscipit lectus velit, eget eleifend massa pretium quis. Cras quis pharetra nulla. Proin porttitor fermentum est, eu aliquam velit porttitor quis. Sed non bibendum odio, a pellentesque neque. Donec eu lectus vitae nisl ornare aliquet. Donec ornare felis non elit malesuada tincidunt. Praesent ipsum augue, venenatis in auctor vel, aliquet et augue. Ut efficitur elit eu elit fringilla, imperdiet suscipit libero consequat. Ut in metus libero. Nullam vestibulum, augue nec varius elementum, erat orci iaculis neque, quis varius ante leo eu lectus. Vestibulum eget ante enim. Nulla lobortis, felis sed mattis posuere, urna leo pharetra mi, ut elementum augue erat sed odio. In mattis, orci nec maximus fermentum, tellus lacus porta purus, sed scelerisque massa justo id nunc."
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "2d9145a0b749ca85959268737c90029c",
          "orderNo": 2,
          "type": "image",
          "image": {
            "id": "e94d4dcdbc45d90d0561116518e13b77",
            "align": "center",
            "src": "lena.gif",
            "caption": "Image caption"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "1dfa4dc8242f7b98b5449d380fee1785",
          "orderNo": 3,
          "type": "question",
          "question": {
            "id": "7d8826e84a398532fbe78be646214eab",
            "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit?",
            "type": "textarea",
            "required": true,
            "pageFlowModifier": false
          }
        }
      ],
      "namedPage": true
    }
  ]
};

window.survey = new Survey.Model(json);

survey
    .onComplete
    .add(function (sender) {
        document
            .querySelector('#surveyResult')
            .textContent = "Result JSON:\n" + JSON.stringify(sender.data, null, 3);
    });

$("#surveyElement").Survey({model: survey});
```

My Project PreView Here: [Wasiliuk](http://wasiluk.io/angular-surveys/#/model) - by clicking Model  JSON has generates.

Comment: You want to create a pure HTML form from the version of a Google Form?

Comment: Yeah, just press button click ... I'll get this fully functional HTML file of -> Viewer Section.

Comment: is it even possible to create all in one file ? After ... I'll need to send it to someone else... And they will fill this form

Comment: They will fill this form and resend to me.

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't possible. The JSON itself does not contain all the data needed to recreate the form. Note that each field contains some IDs, I believe these IDs are used to query the actual form data. But important information such as questions and answer options are not available in the JSON.

Comment: Hey , yeah found some info , that is not possible due security etc... Could you please answer this question ? I will mark it as Solved for you ;) ♥